# Is it safe to chain AsEnumerable and AsQueryable?

Tags: c#

I have an extension method that can operate on both `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`. The method parses input and calls `Skip().Take()` in the end.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRange<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> target,
    RangeHeaderValue range
    )
```

This method works on an `IQueryable` but it returns an `IEnumerable`. So I add another method to convert, call the first method and convert again:

```
public static IQueryable<T> SelectRange<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> target,
    RangeHeaderValue range
    )
{
    return target.AsEnumerable().SelectRange(range).AsQueryable();
}
```

Is it safe to chain convert like this? I'm worried that it could interfere with the `IQueryable` provider, running the method on an in-memory collection instead. I understand the basics of lazy/eager loading but it's quite a complicated topic and I don't want to just assume it'll work.

---

*Note:* the accepted answer is correct about the danger of chaining, but I'd like to add that implementing the `IQueryable` method and calling it from the `IEnumerable` one (so simply switching things around) is safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; that is not a good idea.

Calling `AsEnumerable()` will materialize the entire query, then run `Skip()` and `Take()` on the client.

You need to make a separate (and identical) version of the method that takes and returns `IQueryable<T>` which only calls Queryable methods, so that the query can run on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: **Maybe**

`AsEnumerable()` **might** materialize your query. The easiest way to find out is getting the [SQL Server Express Profiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) and debug side by side to see when is it exactly that the query gets invoked. In fact, `IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable`.

Furthermore, when debugging: if you try to see what's going on, the IDE might materialize it to show it in the nice VS floating GUIs debugging tools

In my experience: jumping back and forth from `AsEnumerable()` to `AsQueryable()` doesn't materialize it until I invoke an `ToArray()`, `ToList()` or any other that inherits from `ICollection`, but keep in mind that `IQueryable` keeps calculation in-memory similar to a Graph. So even if you don't actually see it querying against the DataBase, at a memory low level you might be looking at some performance cost.

Same as you are, I was trying to avoid generating dups in my *Repository Pattern*, specially when it came to pagination:

```
public static class Paginate
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerable<T>(int records, int iPage, IEnumerable<T> input) where T : class { return input.Skip(records * iPage).Take(records); }

// My internal OCD hates this dup >.o
    public static IQueryable <T> Queryable <T>(int records, int iPage, IQueryable <T> input) where T : class { return input.Skip(records * iPage).Take(records); }
}
```

But I ended up doing so just in the case I could avoid an issue that would stall me an entire morning chasing a god-forsaken bug to end up against a dead-end with facing a message written note attached to the wall saying *"I told you so"*